# how to open file using javascript in html

Tags: javascript, html

hey I am working in html and using javascript for programming, I'm a beginner

Here is the problem I am facing.

Suppose I have a folder named 'work'. I have kept my .html file into it.
I have also put some .jpg files in the same folder 'work'.

If i have to access a .jpg file from the 'work' folder I can use this:

img src="smiley.jpg"

now suppose I have a doc file(excel, text and may be pdf) in the same folder 'work'  how can access these doc files the same way I have accessed my .jpg files from the same folder

Comment: You don't have direct access to the filesystem through html files...

Comment: try `<a href="file.pdf">file.pdf</a>`

Comment: Suppose I don't want to open the file in html page instead of that I , want to open them in their respective applications, is it possible

Comment: I used <a href="file.pdf">file.pdf</a>   but its not working

Answer (score 0):

For showing PDF files in web browser you can use [PDF.js](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) or using [Embed Tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_embed.asp) .

```
<embed src="helloworld.pdf">
```

**UPDATE Using PDF.js**

for using pdf.js at first download pdf.js from [github](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js) and then see the example [`helloworld`](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/tree/master/examples/helloworld). this example have three files, [index.html](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/examples/helloworld/index.html) that refrence with script and canvas tag. canvas tag hold your pdf files. and a javascript file that named [hello.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/examples/helloworld/hello.js) in this file you describe your pdf file

```
PDFJS.getDocument('helloworld.pdf')
```

this line thel PDFJS open helloworld.pdf .

for seeing how it work you can see this [demo](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html)

Comment: I am using <embed src="helloworld.pdf">  in my code its not working     Is there a different way to use PDF.js

Comment: @Gajju im Update how to using pdf.js